# compare the data between two variables and generate a report in to the text file

Tags: linux, oracle, shell

my requirement is transfer the data from source data base to the target database
job1.

```
sourcedatabase:oracle.      target
table1                      target1.lst
table2                      table2.lst
table3                       table3.lst
```

this part i done successfully.

job 2.
now i want to count the number of records source database and target database
this part also done successfully.

job3:  ...........(this part only i am lacking)
i kept the record count between source and target  in variable as well as text file
now tell me how to compare the the values in a variable or a text file(these values are find by using select count(*) from table and wc -l $filename.) that i may find the loading process done successfully or not and also i want maintain a log file also

please enhance me how to compare the values in a text file or a variable so that i can maintain a log file to generate a report maintain in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear where these text files came from and why to compare to them. Why don't you store the counts in the database in first place (instead of/in addition to writing them to a file).

> > text file or a variable

What variable? In Oracle PL/SQL you can compare variables using =, !=, is null, is not null, etc. In any other programming language: there are comparison operators too.